# How to make the overlay width and height fixed in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

for example

```
 // Common overlay image input
 String commonOverlayImage = '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20230530_201349.jpg';

 // First execution
 String backgroundImage1 = 'storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20230530_201359.jpg'; // width: 2448, height: 3264
 String outputPath1 = '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/outputPath1.jpg';
 String command1 = '-y -i $backgroundImage1 -i $commonOverlayImage -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=500:500[ovrl];[0:v][ovrl]overlay=100:100" $outPutPath1';

 // Second execution
 String backgroundImage2 = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/images.jpeg'; // width: 736, height: 272
 String outputPath2 = '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/outputPath2.jpg';
 String command2 = '-y -i $backgroundImage2 -i $commonOverlayImage -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=500:500[ovrl];[0:v][ovrl]overlay=100:100" $outPutPath2';
```

the previous two executions work fine but the issue is commonOverlayImage look difference in width and height and position too , however they have the same values and this because the difference of backgroundImage1 and backgroundImage1 dimensions

How can i make them fixed and look the same always whatever backgroundImage dimensions is

Comment: use scale2ref: `[1][0]scale2ref=w=iw/5:h=iw/5[l][v];[v][l]overlay=W-w+w/8`

Comment: kindly can you provide me it with same values in my question ?

Comment: that? `[1][0]scale2ref=w=iw*500/2448:h=iw*500/2448[f][b];[b][f]overlay=w/5:h/5`

Comment: thaaaaaank you maaaaaaaan , please make it as answer to accept it .. it work as expected but i dont know how it work .. please more explanation .. thaaaaaaanks .. tell me please what is mean 'iw' and so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[scale2ref](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref)

```
ffmpeg -i "2448x3264.jpg" -i "1920x1920.jpg" -lavfi "
[1][0]scale2ref=w=iw*500/2448:h=iw*500/2448[l][b];
[b][l]overlay=w*100/500:h*100/500
" out.jpg -y
```

`iw` → input width = 2448, so `w` → output width = 2448 * 500 / 2448 = 500, same as `scale=500:500`

if input width = 736, then output width = 736 * 500 / 2448 = 150, same as `scale=150:150`

if add rotate:

```
ffmpeg -i "736x272.jpg" -i "1920x1920.jpg" -lavfi "
[1][0]scale2ref=iw*500/2448:iw*500/2448[l][b];
[l]pad='hypot(iw,ih)':ow:-1:-1:color=black@0,rotate=1:c=none[l];
[b][l]overlay=W*500/2448*350/500-w/2:x
" out3.jpg -y
```

where 350 = 100 + 500 / 2 center of overlay picture

Comment: when i use the same scenario in scale filtter i notice it also the same good result scale=2448*500/2448.0:h=2448*500/2448.0 , any hint ?

Comment: `scale2ref` gets input width from first pic and change width of second pic

Comment: thank you my friend , you make my days easy learning these points , however when i decide to add rotate ,rotate=1:c=none:ow=rotw(1):oh=roth(1) so the overlay position seems to be not the same position that provided , any fix for this issue , any line from you going to be so thankful my friend .. kindly i need your help 

Comment: pad transparent border, rotate, overlay `[l]pad='hypot(iw,ih)':ow:-1:-1:color=black@0, rotate=PI/4:c=none[l]; [b][l]overlay=W*500/2448*350/500-w/2:x` where 350 is center of overlay pic

Comment: thank you again , after many tests i failed to add these lines to your answer , it give me error in syntax ,kindly my teacher could you add this to your answer with same values in full so i can run it correctly and study it . same value i mean which is scale2ref 500:500 and overlay 100:100 and background 2448 , and rotate 1 in our case .. same values in answer

Comment: No such filter: 'ih):ow:-1:-1:color' .. i am using the full version of FFmpeg

Comment: try to add backslash `pad=hypot(iw\,ih):ow...`

Comment: thank you yes it work now , and result is awesome , but i cannot understand where is the 100 ? i mean overlay:100:100 , what if i want to put overlay:800:800 instead how the line look like ?

Comment: if 100 → `overlay=W*500/2448*(100+500/2)/500`, if 800 → `overlay=W*500/2448*(800+500/2)/500`

Comment: You know @ Баяр Гончикжапов , i was making Graduation Project , without your answers to me i am losing my times , your answer was displayed on my classroom with students  .. really thank you so mush like millions .. i appreciate every word you wrote .. ♥♥♥ you such as angel from the sky came to help me ♥♥ without your help i am nothing with this project